# Security - I have tried to log in with my ssh key into the wrong address

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, putty

I have tried to log in (SSH) into the wrong address, my AWS instance was off so I guess no-ip redirected to the old IP address. My private key was specified at putty configuration, is there any security issues regarding this exposure ? I mean, someone could exploit this kind of mistake to steal the key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no issue here, your private key is not exposed as part of the  exchange.